# Strip tox path from pytest-cov output

Tags: python, pytest, tox, pytest-cov

When using pytest and [pytest-cov](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov/) with [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/). My `tox.ini` is

```ini
[tox]
envlist = py3

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-codeblocks
    pytest-cov
commands =
    pytest {tty:--color=yes} {posargs} --cov=mypackagename
```

The output will contain the full tox path of the files, e.g.:

```
---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.11.1-final-0 -----------
Name                                                                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.tox/py3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mypackagename/__init__.py                              1      0   100%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                                                      678    168    75%
```

I'm not interested in the prefix `.tox/py3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`. Is there any way to remove it from the output?

```
mypackagename/__init__.py                                 1      0   100%
```

Comment: Is this project publicly available? If so, please provide a link.

I have an idea, but want to try it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. tox runs your tests on the installed project, not local code. Coveragepy can remap from installed to local via https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.0.1/config.html#paths. See tox itself https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/main/pyproject.toml#L98